# FUEL CMS / CodeIgniter issue with jQuery Accordion - Not Working @ all

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, fuelcms

I cannot get the jQuery UI Accordion to work inside one of my very simple CodeIgniter Views, not sure what is going on but I suspect it has something to do with how I linked the files. I have tried every possible combination of relative URL I can think of.

Here is my Controller that loads my header view and then the primary view. This is working as I can see all of the HTML, just the jQuery isnt doing its thing:

**Controller:**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
    {
      $this->load->view('header');
      $this->load->view('main');
    }
}
```

My 2 Views:

**HEADER VIEW**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>my site</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="ROBOTS" content="ALL" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="<?=fuel_var('meta_keywords')?>" />
  <meta name="description" content="<?=fuel_var('meta_description')?>" />
  <!-- Base Spider CSS -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
  <!-- [END] -->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" />

  <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
</script>
```

**MAIN VIEW**

```
<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
      <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
      <div>Second content</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I echo my base_url() I get http://www.mywebsite.com/site1/**

My CSS, JS and other assets are in a folder at the site root level
+ assets
   + js
   + css
   + images

I have made sure the folders are all writable, not sure what else it could be.
The controller is rendering the view correctly and the HTML is showing up, just no jQuery action.

Comment: "view source" on the rendered page and see what the generated paths look like. In Firefox you can click the path and be sure it loads the js, if all of it loads then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Looking at the source the URL is correct:
      <script src="http://www.sdi.myspiderdesign.com/fuel/assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>      
      <script src="http://www.sdi.myspiderdesign.com/fuel/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Is all of the HTML there as well? Including your #accordion div?

Comment: Yea sure is, the HTML is rendering just fine: http://sdi.myspiderdesign.com/fuel/index.php/mobile

Comment: It looks like everything is there except for the important <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
</script>  part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the jquery function in your rendered HTML:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sweet jesus that may be the dumbest thing I ever posted. Thanks again John, always helps having a second set of eyes look at it.